# Issue with Treeview item update when passing as a parameter

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

I have following test code, I am updating `m_ClientTreeView` by calling `createTreeView(TreeView tree)` method by passing it. But even treeview is a refrence type, the change is not reflecting back. I checked with ref and it is working properly.

```
 namespace TestRefType
 {
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
      public Form1()
      {
        InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         ClientGUI objCGUI = new ClientGUI();
         createTreeView(objCGUI.m_ClientTreeView);
         //createTreeView(ref objCGUI.m_ClientTreeView);

         objCGUI.m_ClientTreeView.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
      }

     private void createTreeView(TreeView tree)
     {
         tree = new TreeView();
         tree.Visible = false;
     }
}

  public struct ClientGUI
  {
     public System.Windows.Forms.TreeView m_ClientTreeView;
  }
}
```

What might be the reason?

Comment: You can not expect to see `TreeView` which you created in code. Currently It hasn't been added to any form. It's just an in-memory object which is a member of your `ClientGUI` structure.

Comment: I mean when I checked objCGUI.m_ClientTreeView after called createTreeView, it is still holding null value

Comment: That's because you didn't perform any changes to `m_ClientTreeView`. If you want to assign a new value to it, pass it as `ref`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although `TreeView` is a reference type but **it doesn't mean** you can change its reference when you pass it to a method.

When you pass a reference type to a method, you can change its members but you can not change reference of object. To change the reference of the object you need to use `ref` keyword in method signature and when passing the instance to the method.

Without using ref, when you pass `objCGUI.m_ClientTreeView` to `createTreeView(TreeView tree)` to method, in the method, `tree` is just a variable which points to a `TreeView`. You can access and change `tree.SomeProperty`, but if you say `tree = new TreeView()` then you just said the `tree` variable in your method scope point to a new `TreeView`. Outside of the method, `objCGUI.m_ClientTreeView` contains the value which it had before passing to the method.

**Example**

Here is a really simplified example about what you did:

```
TreeView t1 = null;
TreeView t2 = t1;
t2 = new TreeView();
```

What do you expect from `t1` now?

**Note 1:** When using a reference type in a structure, you should be careful when using the structure. Although structures are value type but when copying, their reference types don't copy and keep the same references between different instance of that structure, for example if you add node to the `TreeView` of the copied structure, the node also will be added to the first instance of your structure.

**Note 2:** Here is a great article by Joseph Albahari about reference type and value type. It probably will solve most of your problems about the concept:

- [C# Concepts: Value vs Reference Types](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx)